# Laravel ReflectionException Class does not exist in SendReport job

Tags: laravel

I want to send email with pdf attachment in SendReport job.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Site;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Repositories\PositionRepository;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as Pdf;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendReport extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $email = '';

    private $period = '';

    private $siteId = -1;

    public function __construct(string $email, string $period, int $siteId)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->period = $period;
        $this->siteId = $siteId;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $site = Site::find($this->siteId);
        $period = $this->period;

        $repo = new PositionRepository();
        list($searchRequests, $positions) = $repo->getTodayPositions($site);

        $pdf = Pdf::loadView(
            'report.report',
            compact('site', 'period', 'searchRequests', 'positions')
        );
        $content = $pdf->output('report.pdf');

        $user = User::where('email', $this->email)->first();

        Mail::queue(
            'emails.report',
            [
                'user' => $user,
            ],
            function ($m) use ($user, $content) {
                $m->to($user->email, $user->name)
                    ->cc(env('ADMIN_EMAIL'))
                    ->subject('Report');

                $m->attachData($content, 'Report.pdf', [
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

But it shows me `ReflectionException in Container.php line 738: Class does not exist`. If I save pdf to file and then use attach($pathToFile, ...) instead of attachData($pdfContent, ...) it works. Or if I don't pass $content to Closure, all is ok, message is sent.

```
Mail::queue(
    'emails.report',
    [
        'user' => $user,
    ],
    function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)
            ->cc(env('ADMIN_EMAIL'))
            ->subject('Report');
    }
);
```

Maybe pdf size is too big? I want to use exactly attachData() instead of attach($pathToFile, ...).

Comment: Does it say which class does not exist?